# What relay do i need to control 220v 16amp motor (water pump)?

Tags: arduino, relay

I am new to Arduino and Digital electronics, I have purchased an Arduino UNO, and want to control my water pump from it.

The water pump works on 220V and 15A.

can you guide me on this spec? what relays do i need etc?

Comment: Whats power rating of motor? 3.3kW??

Comment: @seetharaman with a single phase induction motor 3.3KVA gets you about 2KW mechanical power

Comment: @seetharaman it's a 
1 HP pump
1KW
8 stage Oli filled Motor...   that's what the box says

Comment: is it good for my project ? http://www.ebay.in/itm/30A-5V-6V-Relay-Board-Module-With-optocoupler-For-8051-PIC-AVR-ARM-ARDUINO-/152365494754?hash=item2379b0f1e2:g:9mwAAOSwUuFWz9DM

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must be careful when choosing the relay. Firstly, it must be appropriate for the your circuit power supply. For Ex. if your power supply is 5V DC, then you have to choose one which its supply voltage is 5V DC. Secondly,its contact current must be appropriate for the your load current (water pump). My sugggest is that you should choose **min. 20A and over** one in your circuit.

And I have attached an circuit about your question, you can connect a pump instead of the ac bulb.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fg7X2A.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: Current level is regular for a relay, if it needed higher current, then contactor must be used. In my Opinion, a relay is reasonable for that circuit.

Comment: Where can I get 20A and over relay with 5V DV as a supply voltage. do we have such thing available for Arduino, I apologise as i am new to electronics?

Comment: Not 5V, it only supplies relay, and the pump is suplied from AC voltage source, so the current (around 20A) is drawn by it.

Comment: all of the ones I've seen pre-wired  for arduino are only good for switching 10A or less,  you'll probably need to get a larger relay separately and either try to substitute it onto the board or use a small relay or a transistor circuit to switch it power for it.